# ¿Qué hacer con usuarios que abiertamente votan a favor de malas preguntas y respuestas solo para llevar la contraria?

Tags: discusión

Como varios aquí, hay veces que observo votos que no tienen mucho sentido. Pero bueno, como no se sabe quién los hace, entonces uno sigue adelante sin preocuparse de esas cosas. Y de todos modos, cada quién tiene derecho a su propio criterio.

Pero, se debería hacer algo más si nos topamos con un usuario que a propósito, y sin esconderlo, vota contario a los votos existentes por razones que claramente van en contra de lo aceptado como comunidad?

Mi pregunta surge a raíz de los comentarios hechos por el usuario [@Máxima Alekz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6046/m%c3%a1xima-alekz) en el hilo siguiente: [Count en My SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43963/count-en-my-sql/).

En su estado original, la pregunta no era clara. Era el típico caso de "No funciona", pero sin detalles ni explicación de si recibía algún error. Por supuesto, le di un voto negativo + voto de cierre (particularmente porque no se trata de un usuario nuevo, y no es la primera vez que hace eso) y comenzé a redactarle un comentario para pedirle que agregue más información.

Entre tanto, también se agregó la respuesta típica que intenta adivinar el problema. Pero la respuesta era obviamente incorrecta, así que le di un voto negativo por adivinar y por sugerir una consulta SQL inválida.

Para mi sorpresa, tanto la pregunta como la respuesta enseguida recibieron votos a favor. Y el usuario en cuestión explicó sus votos en los comentarios:

> Te he dado +1 por preguntar de forma casual. :)
>
> +1 Por intento de respuesta.

Traté de llamarle la atención al respecto:

> Sin la coma, el SQL no es válido. De todas maneras, OP no ha explicado bien su problema. (y por favor, @Máxima, no voten a favor simplemente para compensar votos negativos o para recompensar intentos. Los votos deberían ir de acuerdo a si la respuesta es útil o no)

Y su respuesta:

> Shhhh. Si no se enseña a preguntar, no critiques ni en lo minimo.

Y la mía:

> @Máxima: ¿A que te refieres? Hay muchos enlaces disponibles [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) para orientar a los usuarios a mejorar las preguntas. La idea es que este sitio sea útil a la comunidad, pero para eso se necesita que como comunidad moderemos la calidad de las preguntas y respuestas. Y los votos son un medio de hacerlo.

Y una más de su parte:

> JAJAJAJA, por favor no me vengas con eso. Eso muy pocos lo miran, enseña tú a preguntar y responder pues, en StackOverflow no hay reglas. La comunidad (todos sin excepción) hacen a StackOverflow lo que es. So don't say anything.

Y luego en otros comentarios hasta le sugiere a OP que borre la pregunta, pero con una justificación pobre:

> Te recomiendo que elimines la pregunta antes de que lleguen los downvoters. Y los que dan reportar. Ni miran por qué reportan, sólo siguen al primero que reporta. :))

Entonces, nuevamente, mi pregunta es: ¿es necesario hacer algo con usuarios así? ¿Se necesita reportarlos de alguna forma? O, ¿hay que respetar que tienen derecho a votar como les dé las ganas, y mejor ignorarlos?

Comment: Esto mas que una pregunta parece una queja muy elaborada. Si acaso es una pregunta, mi respuesta es: **ignora**.

Comment: @toledano: Lo siento si solo suena a queja. No voy a mentir: no me agradaron sus comentarios para nada. Me parecieron falta de respeto. Pero mi pregunta no es en cuanto a eso en realidad. Poniendo de lado el tono de sus comentarios, es obvio que su forma de pensar y actuar (en este caso en cuanto a la forma como vota) no concuerda con lo que se ha decidido para esta comunidad. De modo que mi duda es, ¿qué es lo correcto? ¿Moderar o ignorar ese comportamiento descarado? ¿Tiene él razón en realidad: que en StackOverflow no hay reglas y cada quién hace lo que le da la gana?

Comment: Publicación mala eliminada.

Comment: por cierto, la pregunta fue eliminada a pesar de que en SOen hay una pregunta idéntica http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840253/sql-count-not-working

Comment: Antes de ver esta publicación (y antes de que se eliminara la pregunta), reporté los comentarios como "*Hay múltiples comentarios sobre una discusión sin sentido en la pregunta y las 2 respuestas que creo que habría que eliminar porque no agregan nada*" y fueron eliminados

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Abrí una nueva publicación referida a la eliminación de esta pregunta: [Excepciones al cierre por “un error tipográfico”](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1300/127), que fue lo que pensé al momento de verla y dudar si votar para cerrarla o no.

Comment: @ReneLimon bueno, hasta en SOen pueden pasar preguntas que no se cierran/eliminan sino después de años.

Comment: Yo no he visto esos links de bienvenida al sitio ni como preguntar. He aprendido por mi propia cuenta, así que es eso aprendido lo que se enseña. No se le dice al usuario, *tome esos links y bienvenido*.

Comment: Y yo no dije que todos hacen lo que se les da la gana, dije que StackOverflow es lo que es por **la comunidad**. StackOverflow no tiene **reglas** en sentido de que votas negativo o positivo a tu pensar si no te parece o te parece. O algunos otros porque el usuario no les agrada. La comunidad hace lo que cree correcto, si tu reportas a cierre mis preguntas estás dando **tus razones**, porque tú **consideras** que mi pregunta está mal, o que no sirve.

Comment: Y yo no doy -1 a no ser de que me fastidies. No es mi estilo, no doy -1 y ya. Motivo a que los usuarios sientan que deben ser mejores en sus preguntas y respuestas, e inclusive prevenir que puedan perder sus puntos

Comment: Ya que no hay nada mejor que tu rank y tus puntos en StackOverflow, es ese toque de interés especial que tiene la página para los usuarios, así que recibir un -1 no es nada agradable. Por eso mis respuestas para aquellos principiantes no es ruda, es amistosa. No como otros personajes, que sólo quisieran ver perfección, así no son las cosas. Ese es mi punto de vista.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿Qué es lo correcto? ¿Moderar o ignorar ese comportamiento descarado?

En mi opinión, se deben hacer **ambas** - *(no importa la cantidad de reputación u otra característica del usuario problemático)*.

Yo seguiría estos pasos:

1. Reporta el comentario como irrespetuoso u ofensivo.
2. *Si consideras responderle con un comentario*, recuérdale que existen unas [normas de comportamiento que todos seguimos en la comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).
3. *Si este usuario responde negativamente*, **no le respondas con otro comentario**, simplemente, repite el paso 1 y evita responderle*.

   - Ya que este usuario puede ser un *troll*.

*Si no estoy equivocado*, hay herramientas para reportar usuarios. Yo llegaría a este extremo si este usuario insiste en su comportamiento.

Hay que aclarar que no se trata de nada personal, pero, como usuario de Stack Exchange<sup>1</sup> has seguido lo que cualquier otro usuario haría: [ser amable :)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

---

<sup>1</sup> He mencionado *Stack Exchange* ya que este comportamiento no es exclusivo de Stack Overflow en Español.