# ¿Como actuar frente a empresas, externos que redirigen sus foros acá?

Tags: discusión

Me preguntaba si alguien está encargado de evitar que ocurran confusiones como la de la pregunta reciente eliminada:

[ ATENCION, MUCHOS INSULTOS ]

> [image: imagen]

En la que claramente se ve que un usuario de una plataforma externa llega enfurecido reclamando a SO como si este fuera es servicio al cliente oficial. Recientemente navegué por el sitio y algunos enlaces redirigían acá como soporte [[Ejemplo]](https://www.mercadopago.cl/developers/es/community/).

Comment: Solo es una empresa, __Mercado Libre__ y es el primer caso. No es para tanto. Del asunto ya está informado @JuanM y ha tomado las medidas que la empresa SE considera necesaria. Los usuarios deberíamos a) actuar con calma o b) como les dicte su conciencia. A mi mi conciencia me dicta actuar con la opción "a": con calma.

Comment: En realidad no es el primer caso, es como el tercero :P y tampoco es la única empresa, he visto al menos 3 (otros desarrolladores tambien los hacen en el sitio en inglés). Pero claro solo quería saber que sucedía en estos casos :P

Comment: Pues en unos cuantos minutos se cerró y le llovieron votos negativos. La moderación funcionó bastante rápido, yo creo que deberíamos seguir así. Yo ni siquiera me enteré.

Comment: @toledano esa es la solución de la comunidad, pero sigue sin resolverse el problema de fondo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Y que puede hacer la comunidad para resolver el problema de fondo? Ya está enterado Juan, ya se puso en contacto con la gente de MP, aparte de avisarle, que otra cosa podemos hacer? El otro problema es que nadie le contesta a esos usuarios. No son muchas preguntas a la semana, pero ahí siguen y continuan llegando.

Comment: @toledano además de los votos en contra, votos de cierre y votos de eliminación, **reportar la publicación** para que quede como huella de problemas ocasionados en nuestra plataforma debido a estas empresas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza de hecho veo que existen las etiquetas [tag:mercadolibre] y [tag:mercadopago]. ¿Las permitimos en SOes?

Comment: El problema que veo es que tal y como lo tiene puesto MercadoLibre/MercadoPago, parece que SOes es parte de ellos: no dicen que sea un servicio externo y poco más o menos que dan a entender (unilateralmente) que somos su soporte técnico.

Comment: @fedorqui se deben permitir porque son etiquetas válidas: Ayudan a identificar el problema como lo hacen las etiquetas de otras compañías (Twitter, Facebook, PayPal...) No hay problema en que existan esas etiquetas

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro bien visto, tienes toda la razón. He visto muchas preguntas en SO del tipo [Should we burninate \[godaddy\]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331817/1983854) y me dejé llevar por eso. Si son preguntas en que esa información es relevante, será correcto añadir tal etiqueta.

Answer (score 16):

La verdad es que poner *Foro de desarrolladores --> Para que consultes lo que quieras* y un enlace a Stack Overflow en español muestra un poco de jeta :-D

Una empresa puede dirigir sus preguntas a este sitio, ¡por supuesto! Esto nos debería congratular en tanto que significa que consideran que nosotros somos una buena fuente de información y ayuda. ¡Buen trabajo!

**Pero**, y hay un pero importante aquí, estas preguntas deben pasar por el mismo filtro que todas las demás. Es decir, deben cumplir lo dicho en [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> - un problema específico de programación, o
> - un algoritmo de software, o
> - herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
> - un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

Por tanto, contesta o vota para cerrar libremente, tal y como haces con cualquier otra pregunta.

Esto es más o menos lo que se comenta en la pregunta FAQ de Stack Overflow 
[Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1983854) (traducida en [¿Por qué no somos soporte al cliente de [tu compañía favorita]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/83)). Allí se hace hincapié en que las preguntas de servicio técnico no se pueden hacer aquí a menos que entren dentro de la lista arriba indicada. Creo importante destacar la sección final:

> ### ¡Pero la compañía [X] me envió aquí para recibir asistencia técnica!
>
> Sí. Para tus preguntas que son on-topic, relacionadas con la programación. Para tus preguntas que tengan que ver específicamente con escribir código para su API. Pero para preguntas que involucran temas de asistencia técnica, debes contactar con la empresa directamente.
>
> Si la compañía que te envió aquí no te dio una guía clara de qué tipo de preguntas encajan bien en Stack Overflow, [ponte en contacto con el Community Team](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) para explicárselo; puede que tengan la manera de ponerse en contacto con la empresa y ayudarlos a establecer unas pautas claras para evitar la confusión.

---

Ejemplo de pregunta que debemos cerrar: [Cobrar el cargo Mercadopago al cliente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/68558/83):

> Hola he implementado la API mercadopago en una pagina y funciona bien, pero quisiera saber si hay posibilidad de que la comision Mercadopago la pague el cliente y asi uno recibir el valor neto de la venta.

Comment: Yo lo veo un poco como que SO debe funcionar como un FAQ para los desarrolladores, no 'para que consultes lo que quieras' porque efectivamente en SO no 'consultamos lo que queremos', sino lo que toca. De hecho, es un arma de doble filo, porque cuando el cliente de la empresa haga un par de preguntas/comentarios fuera de lugar, como el ejemplo expuesto, y se elimine o tenga 'downvotings' le reclamará a la empresa (con toda la razón: tú me envías a un 'foro' donde no me dejan preguntar!!). Es más, SO no es un foro es un QA site. Así que no veo mal el redirect, lo que hay que plantearlo bien.

Comment: @HEDMON estoy muy de acuerdo con lo que comentas. Si está bien definido, la combinación <una empresa> <-> SO puede ser una gran simbiosis. De lo contrario, puede acabar dando mala imagen a ambos: a la empresa por delegar la ayuda en otros y a SO por dejar sin respuesta a mucha gente. Por cierto, ¡la página que enlazas en un perfil da un error!

Comment: gracias, fixed ;) Era el link a mi sitio viejo que ya no uso, lo actualicé al blog (que la verdad tampoco actualizo mucho)

Comment: @fedorqui justo estaba buscando este post cuando vi la pregunta que mencionas =)

Comment: @jasilva probablemente si cerramos todas las que no son de programación, Mercadopago recibirá quejas y se replanteará su forma de abordar el problema. Qué lástima que quienes sufran las consecuencias sean sus usuarios.

Answer (score 6):

No hay ningun problema que una empresa envie a sus usarios a este sitio para soporte, por el contrario, es recomendable y habla bien de nuestra comunidad.

Para quien no lo sabe, Microsoft pone explicitamente vinculos a StackOverflow original en muchos de sus projectos para quienes buscan soporte (aputando a una etiqueta, igual que en este caso). Y se que empleados de microsoft monitorean en bases regulares las etiquetas del proyecto en que trabajan.

El punto cuestionable de este caso, es que en MP no sean explicitos en decir que se trata de SOES (un sitio externo) y no de un soporte interno. No creo que se puda hacer mucho, salvo incurririendo en gastos y en ese caso, es StackExchage quien deberia evaluar si es necesario/vale la pena hacerlo.

Sin embargo, Yo celebro esto. Creo que es una señal de que nuestra comunidad va ganado notoreidad y que hay empresas importantes como mercadopago que confia en nosotros, en la plataforma de Q&A, y quiza alguno de sus empleados monitorea dichos tags.

La recomendacion seria: Poner el vinculo a SOES, incluyendo una leyenda aclarando que se trata de un sitio externo, nosotros.

Con respecto a la pregunta en si, claramente este usuario necesita: aprender a comunicarse, luego hecharle un vistazo al *recorrido* y luego quiza una mirada a *¿que cosas puedo preguntar aqui?* y porque no ... XD o se trata de un trol, en cualquier caso el vinculo a nuestra comunidad no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: En realidd **sí hay un problema** y es que de **debe haber una coordinación previa entre la empresa y StackOverflow para hacerlo**.

Comment: Un problema está en esta parte: "_empleados de microsoft monitorean en bases regulares las etiquetas del proyecto en que trabajan_". Me parece que esta empresa no tiene en mente poner a ningún empleado a responder preguntas, sino que espera que nosotros seamos esos empleados. Y como dice Luiggi, lo ha hecho sin coordinación previa y sin notificar nada

Comment: ¿y stackoverflow debe gastar tiempo/dinero en validar si aceptar o no una empresa? no tiene objeto pues eso lo haremos nosotros, si la pregunta es offtipic la cerramos, si es maleducado la borramos, etc. Es Mercadopago quien se perjudica si no monitorea sus propios tags, SOES no se perjudica en lo mas mínimo. Amen de que internet es publica y cualquiera puede vincular cualquier cosa sin pedirle permiso a nadie.

Comment: StackOverflow recibe compensación por parte de algunas empresas para resaltar y ayudar con sus etiquetas (ya sea económica o trabajadores respondiendo o como sea). Por eso sí gasta tiempo/dinero en validar ese tipo de cosas. Aparte, no estoy de acuerdo con que no nos afecta a SOes: quedan más preguntas sin responder porque la gente no sabe (que afecta a nuestra reputación), hace que los usuarios no se sientan bienvenidos (lo que hace que no se involucren más), da mala imagen y publicidad (se están asociando las malas prácticas de otra empresa con SOes)...

Comment: SO recibe compensación por las etiquetas promocionadas, eso es otra cosa, esas etiquetas llevan un icono. Con respecto a que afecta negativamente nuestra imagen, no acabo de estar de acuerdo con eso, excepto por el hecho de preguntas sin responder perjudican nuestros numeros para la graduacion. Si acaso nadie monitorea dichos tags, se perjudica la imagen de mercadopago ya que es evidente que este es otro sitio externo; simplemente una plataforma para dar el soporte.

Comment: Ese usuario ha sido incapaz de ver la diferencia, así que tan evidente no debe ser.

Comment: Ese usuario es un ser humano dispuesto a decir cualquier barbaridad, no podemos aplicarle las mismas reglas que a un usuario que trae una duda genuina y/o mira un poco alrededor antes de preguntar. No podemos basar nuestra forma de actuar enfocada en los malintencionados ya que deberían ser la excepción y para ellos tenemos otras herramientas que, de paso, funcionaron a la perfección.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos sí, debe haber esa coordinación previa.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¿debe haber una coordinación previa entre la empresa y StackOverflow para hacerlo? ¿Para hacer qué? Como dice fedorqui, son unos jetas. Pero para poner un enlace a SO no hay que pedirle permiso a nadie. Que coordinarse es bueno está claro. Pero eso depende de su buena voluntad, que más bien parece ser poca, y no se puede hacer nada (legalmente) para obligarles.

Answer (score 3):

En cuanto a cómo actuar frente a empresas, no lo sé, pero en cuanto a las preguntas, igual que como lo hacemos con cualquier publicación:

1. Votar
2. Responder
3. Comentar
4. Chatear
5. Publicar en Meta

Todo lo anterior orientado a tener un sitio con contenido que corresponda al tema de programación que sea útil y de calidad para muchos programadores.

Comment: El problema es que casi nadie de aquí tiene conocimiento alguno en este caso de mercado pago :s, esto se resuelve si esa empresa manda a su gente para acá y aprendemos todos.

Comment: @x4mp73r: 1. La pregunta menciona a [tag:mercadopago] como un ejemplo, pero se refiere a cualquier empresa que haga los mismo, por otro lado, es un "problema" inherente del modelo de la red [se], se asume que hay gente interesada en responder preguntas pero esto implica que coincida el interés en responder con los conocimientos necesarios para hacerlo. Siento que queda pendiente reflexionar acerca de cómo atraer expertos a las etiquetas con muchas preguntas y pocas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Como actuar frente a empresas, externos que redirigen sus foros acá?

Si el usuario que ha generado la pregunta "buscando soporte", se pueden aplicar los mismos pasos que se aplican a cualquier pregunta:

- *Si es un usuario nuevo*: comentario de bienvenida, conocer el sitio, mejorar pregunta *"si la pregunta lo requiere"*.
- Votar según la calidad de la pregunta.
- Editar la pregunta *si lo requiere*.
- Responder a la pregunta del OP *(en el campo dispuesto para ello)*.

Para el caso de una pregunta en donde se presuma, se entienda o es claramente una pregunta de tipo soporte, es menester de la comunidad **indicar a ese usuario que la comunidad puede brindarle ayuda**, pero que cualquier modificación/configuración hecha puede generar resultados no esperados.

Ejemplo:

> Stack Overflow en Español no se responsabiliza por pérdida de datos al
>   hacer estos ajustes.<sup>1</sup> -

*Esto también debería quedar resaltado en las respuestas* -.

<sup>1</sup> En su momento leí algo similar en Meta Stack Overflow *en inglés*, pero no tengo el texto a la mano; creo que era "liberación de resposabilidades" o algo así...

---

Respecto al contenido de tu pregunta:

Si la persona que contacta a Stack Overflow en Español u otro sitio de Stack Exchange se comunica de esa manera *(como se puede ver en la captura de pantalla de tu pregunta)*, **no considero que ese contenido merezca o requiera algún tipo de ayuda que permita mejorar su contenido**.

Lo anterior me baso en:

- No se trata de una pregunta.
- Es un usuario sin registrar (o un usuario nuevo).
- Es posible que se trate de un troll *(en serio)*.

Al ver una pregunta/respuesta/comentario similar, sigo estos pasos que enumero en esta [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1299/78).

---

Considero ademas que, si Stack Overflow en Español anima o permite preguntas de tipo soporte, es necesario que la empresa a la que se le brinda soporte:

- Informe a sus usuarios el tipo de contenido que esperamos ver aquí en
  Stack Overflow en Español. Esto, con el fin de evitar mas situaciones así, o que al menos, sean cada vez menos frecuentes.
- Stack Overflow en Español debería informar que ciertas etiquetas son mas orientadas a recibir preguntas de tipo soporte.