# Foro de Mercado Pago

Tags: soporte, preguntas, temática

## ¿Estamos teniendo algún malentendido, o aparente malentendido, con las personas de **Mercado Pago**?

Por lo que los últimos están derivando <s>muchas</s> **preguntas** a nuestro sitio, y realmente ¿deberían hacerlo de tal modo?

Si mal no me equivoco ayer contesté con un comentario [en está pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84430/la-api-responde-invalid-payment-method-id-3028-usando-visa-solamente-a-algunos), y me impactó la respuesta del OP con un tweet de una cuenta de MeLi Developers (MercadoLibre) que referenciaba a SOes como sitio de consulta.

Luego hoy me tocó ver una [nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85729/consultas-sobre-mercadopago) sobre MercadoPago, por lo que orienté al OP a revisarla ya que tenía varios votos negativos, y el mismo me contestó que "***la gente de MercadoPago indicaba que éste (haciendo referencia a SOes) es el foro de desarrolladores***".

Creyendo que es un malentendido, busqué "foro de desarrolladores mercadopago" en Google, y descubrí [en la página de MercadoPago](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/community/) que **efectivamente hacen referencia a SOes**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ese **"Ver más"**, son redirigidos al tag de [MercadoPago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago).

## Aquí viene la cuestión entonces:

No creo que haya inconveniente ni con la gente de MercadoPago, ni con la comunidad de Desarrolladores que pueden estar necesitando de soporte, ayuda y respuestas.

El problema es que estamos albergando una etiqueta, y por lo visto, una solución de soporte sin, quizás, las herramientas necesarias. Ya que **MercadoPago posee una API** y una buena cantidad de sus preguntas **pueden ser sobre el funcionamiento de la misma** será muy difícil responder a dichas preguntas ya que debería existir en realidad usuarios del soporte de MercadoPago que tengan los conocimientos para **responder esas preguntas**.

Por otra parte **si este comportamiento de preguntas crece** también llevará de mucho esfuerzo para explicar porque **SOes no es un foro**, y porque sus **preguntas deben de adoptar un formato**.

## ¿Es entonces correcta la referencia que nos hace MercadoPago?

Disculpen si extendí demasiado la pregunta

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Como actuar frente a empresas, externos que redirigen sus foros acá?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1674/65)

Comment: Aps, **recontra relacionado** Rubén, estoy leyéndolo por lo que no tenía idea de que ya se había hablado sobre el tema. Gracias!

Comment: No quise marcarlo como duplicado, porque en el [chat] se han comentado cosas, y siento que no estoy al día al respecto, pero no te extrañe si alguien mas que si lo está lo hace.

Comment: Por supuesto que no me ofendera en lo absoluto, de algo había escuchado en el Chat pero no estaba para nada seguro, ni mucho menos en conocimiento de la otra discusión.

Comment: @AgustinM. Quizás conviene que incluyas los tweets en tu pregunta, como forma de mostrar que el problema no se solucionó, sino que se empeoró, y que ahora son más los medios por los cuales promueven acciones que impactan negativamente en SOes. Algo que llame un poco la atención a nivel de Stack Overflow como empresa.

Comment: En la otra pregunta [Luiggi Mendoza comentó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1674/como-actuar-frente-a-empresas-externos-que-redirigen-sus-foros-ac%C3%A1#comment4793_1679): _En realidd sí hay un problema y es que de debe haber una coordinación previa entre la empresa y StackOverflow para hacerlo._ Si bien no creo que sea necesaria, ¿se conoce si ha habido tal coordinación o estamos en la misma situación que la otra vez? Dado que el problema aumenta puede que sí sea necesario pedir a Mercadopago que dé más indicaciones a sus usuarios, para no inundarnos de preguntas no aceptables.

Answer (score 1):

### ¿Cómo nos afecta a nosotros?

Constantemente estamos batallando con <strike>miles de</strike>  muchos nuevos usuarios que usan de manera incorrecta el sitio al grado de que durante el día no baja de 30 la cola de revisión de votos de cierre, una de las causas es precisamente que Mercado pago **nos presenta como un FORO**, no como una comunidad de expertos profesionistas de TI orientados a resolver problemas de programación.

### ¿Cómo afecta a los usuarios de mercado pago?

Lo más lógico que pase es que terminen con el privilegio de [preguntar bloqueado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), pues en este sitio preguntar es un privilegio, no un derecho.

### ¿Quién puede hacer algo al respecto?

Quien puede hacer algo al respecto son los moderadores o al menos deben de saber quien si puede hacer algo, al comunicarse directamente con esa empresa para llegar a una solución en el mejor de los términos.

Comment: Y ya se está convirtiendo en algo tedioso explicarles que no tenemos relación con MercadoPago, algunos hasta groseros se ponen. Me dio curiosidad ver como llegan hasta Stack Overflow, y vi que mínimo la página de mx ya no los redirige hasta aquí (o no encontré el link), pero la de ar y cl sí, no revisé las demás.

Comment: "batallando con miles de nuevos usuarios" ¡Ya quisieramos!

Comment: No, los moderadores no son quienes **se deberían** comunicar directamente con esa empresa ya que no está en sus funciones, podrían hacerlo a "cuenta y riesgo" personal como cualquier otro miembro de la comunidad. Si no lo has hecho aún lee [¿Por qué no somos soporte al cliente de \[tu compañía favorita\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/65)

Comment: Quién puede hacer algo en nombre de SOes es un CM (muy distinto a un moderador).

Answer (score -14):

Si te interesan las preguntas de Mercado Libre léelas, respóndelas, vótalas, etc.
Si no te interesan ignóralas.
No importa si sus autores llegaron a SOes desde un enlace en Google, Bing o Mercado Libre.

## ¿Es entonces correcta la referencia que nos hace MercadoPago?

Es **legal(1)** puesto que no hacen afirmacion falsa alguna. SOes es un foro en el sentido de la tercera acepción del diccionario de la RAE:

> . m. Reunión de personas competentes en determinada materia, que
> debaten ciertos asuntos ante un auditorio que a veces interviene en la
> discusión.

Y también es cierto que sea de desarroladores
Mercado Libre no obliga a nadie a seguir sus enlaces ni obliga a nadie en SOes a hacer nada. Ni da información falsa al respecto. Aunque sí da información fácil de malinterpretar, pero esto no es ilegal, si lo fuese también serían ilegales los indescifrables Términos De Uso de muchos programas.

Resumiendo: Mercado Libre puede hacer lo que hace y no hay nada que SO pueda hacer legalmente para evitarlo.

¿Qué tienen que decir al respecto los jefes de SO? Atwood, respondió a una pregunta similar: [Está bien usar Stack Overflow como foro de soporte para un producto o proyecto? (En inglés)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project).

> Creo que la idea de usar Stack Overflow como foro de soporte oficial
> es ir del revés : la comunidad ha de adoptar el proyecto, encontrarlo
> interesante y hablar de ello en Stack Overflow.
>
> Empujar un destino particular desde el interior del proyecto parece
> forzar a la comunidad más que permitirla crecer orgánicamente.
>
> Una forma es como vísteis con Subsonic -- donde ellos simplemente
> proporcional un único enlace a Stack Overflow entre otros enlaces a
> sitios a los que la gente puede ir a discutir Subsonic. Creo que eso
> es una indicación buena y si quieres sembrar el sitio con una o dos
> cuestiones tu mismo, eso está bien también.
>
> Pero externalizar tus foros o el soporte a Stack Overflow solo es
> abusivo y sin duda lo vemos mal.

Si alguien conoce o tiene contacto con Mercado Libre estaría bien sugerirles que pongan otros enlaces a sitios de desarrolladores. Pero que lo hagan o no depende enteramente de su buena voluntad.

(1) Pero yo no soy un abogado.

Comment: Nota: SOes no es un foro, por lo tanto la definición que expones de la RAE no aplicaría para tu respuesta, y por lo tanto, tampoco para esta comunidad.

Comment: Es falso, pero no ilegal, que MercadoLibre defina a SOes como su foro de desarrolladores. Creo no haber mencionado la palabra "ilegal", de hecho, creo que esto pasa por un malentendido de la gente de MercadoLibre. Vote tu respuesta como negativa ya que en realidad ni siquiera la primera línea tiene razón ya que "si no te interesan ignoralas" tampoco es la solucion ya que en realidad están poblando de preguntas mal redactadas, que no poseen respuesta y que sus OP sienten un rechazo por desconocer el real uso de SOes, y por no obtener respuesta. **Esto no beneficia a SOes como tampoco a MP**

Comment: Nunca había estado tan en desacuerdo con una respuesta

Comment: @AgustinM. Si es falso entonces Mercado Libre está dando información falsa a sus clientes, lo cual es una transgresión de la buena fe contractual. No se puede afirmar que la información de la web de Mercado Libre es falsa pero no ilegal. Solo puede ser legal si es cierta. Y si es falsa es forzosamente ilegal.

Comment: @Flxtr Ciertamente esa definición de la RAE de la palabra foro no es la que se usa en esta comunidad. Es un hecho generalizado que esta comunidad no considera que este sitio sea un foro, y yo coincido en esto. Pero no podemos imponer nuestra definición de la palabra foro a ML, nosotros no somos dueños de la lengua Española. ¿Acontece en SOes una reunión de personas competentes en determinada materia? ¿Debatimos ciertos asuntos ante un auditorio? ¿Participa el auditorio en ocasiones? Si la respuesta es tres veces sí entonces ML está en su derecho a usar la palabra foro en sentido amplio...

Comment: ... para referirse a SOes