# ¿Que hacer con las preguntas con la etiqueta [mercadopago]?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Durante el día de hoy algunos usuarios hemos estado hablando en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) sobre el tema que ocupaba gran parte de nuestras colas de revisión hace bastante tiempo, y era ni mas ni menos que las preguntas sobre [<kbd>Mercadopago</kbd>](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago).

El caso es que esas preguntas se reportaban y se cerraban por la comunidad sobre la marcha, pero consultando la etiqueta se puede ver que aun [hay muchas preguntas relacionadas con el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago) (189 a fecha de hoy).

No creo que se deban eliminar todas las preguntas con esa etiqueta, ya que puede haber alguna con suficiente calidad como para permanecer en el sitio, pero he visto algunas que a mi parecer se podrían cerrar ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188952/argentina-woocommerce-y-mercadopago)), entonces mi pregunta es:

**¿Que se debe hacer con las preguntas con la etiqueta <kbd>Mercadopago</kbd>?**

**¿Se debería de eliminar la etiqueta?**

Comment: Relacionadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3073/83 y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2380/83. ¿No ha contactado aún ningún CM con esta empresa? Es un problema que colea casi desde el inicio de SOes.

Comment: viendo [la pagina de soporte de mercado pago](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/faqs/contact/) no consegui algun enlace que apunte a SoEs @fedorqui

Comment: no creo que sea necesario eliminar esa etiqueta, solo "actualizar" diria yo, puede ser util en algunas preguntas formuladas correctamente

Comment: Tenemos alrededor 94k preguntas en el sitio. Las preguntas de [tag:mercadopago] son menos del 1% y de un vistazo rápido parece que en los últimos meses tenemos pocas preguntas (en algunos meses recientes no ha habido ni una que continue hasta hoy día), por lo que considero que no hay que hacer nada especial.