# ¿Por qué no somos soporte al cliente de [tu compañía favorita]?

Tags: soporte, faq, temática

<sup>Traducido de *[Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company])*</sup>

¿Por qué no puedo hacer una pregunta relacionada con servicio al cliente aquí? Por ejemplo, como:

- ¿Cómo obtengo mi código de confirmación de cuenta de desarrollador de Facebook?
- ¿Apple aprobará mi aplicación y bajo cuáles términos?
- ¿De dónde puedo descargar el kit de desarrollador?
- ¿Cuándo se liberará [alguna nueva característica]?

¿Puedo hacer preguntas acerca del uso de sus API? ¿Cómo es esto diferente?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### ¿Por qué no puedo hacer preguntas sobre servicios?

Porque no sabemos la respuesta.

Claro, puede haber alguna alma intrépida que ha navegado esas aguas antes y ha sobrevivido. Ellos podrían ser capaces de ofrecer orientación. Incluso podría haber algún empleado que ocasionalmente merodee por estos lares, pero aquí está el problema:

**No somos servicio al cliente de Apple, Facebook, Google ó MercadoPago.**

No regimos a esas compañías. No tenemos líneas telefónicas, generador de códigos de confirmación o autoridad alguna para tomar decisiones a tu nombre.

No llevamos un seguimiento de los cambios de políticas, con excepción de anécdotas y rumores, así que cualquier respuesta que te demos hoy va a estar equivocada mañana, si no es que ya está equivocada.

Aquí está el otro problema:

**No estamos aquí para actuar como soporte al cliente en representación de ninguna compañía.**

Esa no es nuestra misión. Estamos aquí para ayudarte con tus retos al escribir código. Si ese código involucra algún API de una compañía, perfecto. Nos hace muy feliz ayudarte con eso, pero nosotros no sabemos si tu aplicación será aprobada. No podemos darte un código de confirmación. Nosotros no sabemos cuánto tiempo le tomará a Microsoft liberar esa cosa maravillosa.

Simplemente no lo sabemos. Todo lo que podemos hacer es referirte a servicio al cliente.

### ¡Pero he sido referido aquí por [alguna compañía] para soporte!

Sí. Si tus preguntas corresponden a [la temática de este sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Para tus preguntas que tengan que ver específicamente con escribir código para esa API, pero para preguntas que involucran asuntos de servicios al cliente, debes contactar a la compañía directamente.

Si la compañía referente no te ha dado una orientación clara acerca de los tipos de preguntas que corresponden a Stack Overflow en español, [contacta al equipo de comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) y dales aviso. Ellos podrían contactar a la compañía y ayudarlos a dar una mejor orientación y evitar confusiones para todos.

**Lectura adicional**

- [¿Cuáles son los temas de los que puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [¿Puedo dar soporte a mi producto en este sitio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

**Preguntas relacionadas**

- [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/)
- [¿Como actuar frente a empresas, externos que redirigen sus foros acá?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1674/)

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Añadir que da igual lo que diga la compañía; los términos de uso del sitio no los ponen ni Apple ni Facebook, etc.

Comment: Gracias por eso Rubén! Voy a usarla como referencia bastante seguido.