# ¿Son propias de SOes preguntas sobre gestión de cuentas en Google Play y Apple Store?

Tags: discusión, temática

Últimamente en el trabajo he tenido que aprender cosas sobre aplicaciones móviles: tanto la creación mediante React Native y Expo, como su publicación en las stores Apple Store y Google Play.

Como todo aprendizaje, tiene momentos de duda e incertidumbre, pero poco a poco he ido descubriendo cosas que antes no sabía y no me eran obvias:

- Cómo publicar una aplicación en Apple Store o Google Play.
- Cómo crear una cuenta para una empresa en Apple Store.
- Cómo aceptar una transferencia de una app desde otra empresa a la propia.
- Cómo publicar una actualización de la aplicación mediante Expo.

En fin, una serie de cosas a medio camino entre la burocracia y la programación que a buen seguro muchos programadores se encuentran en su día a día. He encontrado documentación y respuestas tanto en Stack Overflow (en inglés, recompensas mediante :D) como en foros, twitter o las páginas oficiales.

Creo que esta información, recopiladita, podría ser útil a los siguientes que se encuentren en esta situación, pero no quiero publicarlas sin más y que se me cierren por "fuera de ámbito".

Os pregunto pues: ¿Son propias de SOes preguntas sobre gestión de cuentas en Google Play y Apple Store?

Comment: Realmente me parece muy interesante el tema, y es algo que mas tarde o mas temprano es posible que le surja a muchos programadores, pero no termino de ver claro si entrarían en la temática del sitio. Lo veo cerca del límite, pero al final la temática se decide entre todos, asi que veamos que opina la comunidad :)

Comment: Relacionado: [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/15301)

Comment: @Pikoh gracias por enlace! Pensé en publicar una respuesta allí, pero no sé si tiene validez la relación entre votos positivos y negativos de cada respuesta. Creo que una pregunta separada aporta más claridad.

Comment: Me ah tocado tener que empezar a subir las apps a las tiendas tanto como Android como para iOS y fue un dolor de cabeza

Comment: @Bruno me siento menos solo ahora :) Realmente es una tarea ardua!

Comment: **Para quien vota negativo**: esto no es una encuesta de si queremos que valga o no (si fuera así, le pondría la etiqueta [meta-tag:característica-nueva]), sino una consulta sobre si valdría. Parece lo mismo pero no lo es.

Comment: @fedorqui pienso que el voto es algo personalísimo, asi que para mantener la imparcialidad deberias al menos decir: `para quién vota positivo o negativo: ...`

Comment: @eyllanesc es personalísimo, libre y secreto, faltaría más. Ahora bien, el indicador de los votos es bastante claro sobre el voto negativo: _Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil_. Solamente es diferente en Meta para [meta-tag:característica-nueva].

Comment: @fedorqui Segun tu punto de vista tu pudiste haber investigado pero para otro usuario puede ser que no y es válido e irreprochable su voto. Por ello cuando hago publicaciones evito pronunciarme sobre ellos ya que es la manifestación de la comunidad, guste o no nos guste.

Comment: @eyllanesc en ningún caso reprocho el voto, solamente comento mi sorpresa sobre el voto negativo clarificando que no es una encuesta del tipo de característica-nueva. De la misma manera que me parece bien que no te pronuncies sobre los votos en tus publicaciones, a mí me parece bien pronunciarme sobre los votos en las mías, especialmente cuando como en este csao observo algo que puede venir de un malentendido.

Comment: @fedorqui me es válido tu posición, creo que me falto colocar: *IMHO pienso que el voto es algo personalísimo...* :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc cuando dices *pienso* ya queda claro que es tu opinión, no creo necesario añadir el *IMHO*

Answer (score 7):

Yo no veo ningun problema con esto. Instalar una aplicación es parte inherente del desarrollo de la misma. Aunque el servicio sea de un tercero, configurar la cuenta, subir el paquete y todo eso es como "crear" el instalador usando una herramienta particular.

Por lo tanto para mi, estas preguntas son tan validas como las de como generar el instalador en cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: Una consulta, segun tu punto de vista ¿preguntar sobre precios de cuentas o servicios (de Google o App Store) es una pregunta válida?

Comment: En ese caso no, porque el precio puede variar inclusive mientras se esta dando la respuesta, por lo tanto a futuro no seria util. Lo otro tambien puede cambiar (todo cambia) pero el precio es mas volatil y tiene que ver con muchas cosas. no necesariamente haya una respuesta correcta. Y ademas mejor el soporte del servicio para eso que nosotros

Comment: voy a defender obviamente solo para sacar todo el jugo a tu respuesta. Para ello hay que tener claro que las respuestas no dependen del tiempo, es decir una respuesta en un momento puede ser correcta y en alguno tiempo no, pero siempre es una respuesta válida que es distinto a correcta, por ello SO permite seguir respondiendo o actualizar la respuesta antigua. Yendo desde ese punto de vista responder sobre costos es parte del desarrollo de sotfware y si respondo con el precio actual tambien es válido ya que basado con el principio anterior puede ir actualizando cuando cambia

Comment: Responder con lo mismo que dice la pagina del servicio, seria una pregunta que se cerraria por falta de investigacion ;). Una cosa es tratar de entender como hacer ciertos procesos, y otro es contestar con la misma informacion clara y simple (como es el precio de un servicio) que esta en la pagina del servicio ;)

Comment: IMHO cerrar una pregunta por falta de investigación es muy subjetivo(en general, no solo en el tema del post), un novato podria no saber donde buscar un tema ¿y seria correcto cerrar esa pregunta? para mi no.

Comment: Y por eso no cerramos nada sin antes mirarlo con varios ojos ;)

Comment: Muchas veces he visto que se ha cerrado preguntas por este motivo sin realizar ninguna pregunta al AP, solo por seguir a la *manada*

Comment: Si 5 usuarios deciden cerrar una pregunta sin decirle nada a OP, en ese caso no es algo que podamos controlar. nunca nos vamos a poner todos de acuerdo, pero es interesante tratar de tener un concepto general...

Answer (score 5):

Primera vez que respondo en meta :D

A mi entender es viable, con ciertas restricciones.

Se debería matizar que casos son válidos y cuales no, siguiendo un criterio muy simple, a mi entender, si está explicado en la web del gestor/desarrollador de manera clara, concisa y en español (increíblemente hay quien desarrolla sin saber inglés).

En caso de que la documentación no cumpla esos factores, susceptible de añadirse mas para hacer mas férrea la criba, sería aceptable publicar dudas sobre creación o publicación de aplicaciones.

Como ejemplo diré que el tema del SEO y del SEM constan de una parte de desarrollo y otra de publicación/análisis que no tiene que ver con el código, pero que igualmente son importantes para muchas personas que vienen aquí, dado que donde deberían ir estas preguntas está en inglés.

Considero que este sitio es mas un compendio de muchos saberes, algunos nos serán útiles y otros no, de muchas personas distintas. Estos conocimientos, pese a poder encontrarlos en algunos sitios, en inglés, creo que merecen estar aquí también.

Y creo que con esto he dicho lo que pienso, medianamente claro, todas formas, por resumir, si, merece estar aquí, pues un sitio como SOes es para albergar conocimiento, con cuidado eso sí, pero conocimiento al fin y al cabo.

Answer (score 2):

Respondo exponiendo los puntos en contra de aceptar esta propuesta para así poder delimitar mejor en qué casos podríamos aceptar este tipo de preguntas.

Yo pienso que estamos al borde de lo que se llama desarrollo de software. Según mi punto de vista, que una tarea determinada esté en el desarrollo de software no la hace per se una pregunta válida en SO. Si fuese así, entonces preguntar sobre costos de software, licencias, etc, también sería válido, y así se podrían colar otros temas que para mí no son válidos.

Por otro lado asumamos que la comunidad acepta este tipo de preguntas, ¿Solo las preguntas de los servicios de Google Play y App Store serían válidas? ¿Qué otros servicios serian aceptados? ¿Todos los servicios serían aceptados? ¿Si yo publico un servicio podría dar soporte a mis clientes usando SO?

Considerando el punto anterior ¿no creen que sería una puerta abierta para publicar *spam*? Podría disfrazar una pregunta pidiendo información sobre un servicio.

¿Qué piensan sobre esos puntos? ¿Tienen algun otro punto en contra?

---

Tambien quiero señalar que si como persona o empresa pago por un servicio y tengo algun problema en la configuración del servicio lo correcto es pedir soporte a la empresa ya que por algo lo he pagado.

Comment: Entiendo que la respuesta es una respuesta a la respuesta de gbianchi. En mi caso, intentaré delimitar mejor mi pregunta, pues no iba en el sentido de "todo aquello que sea burocracia de programador", sino el caso concreto de gestión de cuentas en las stores.

Comment: @fedorqui Si tienes problemas con configuración de cuentas y estas pagando un servicio entonces debes pedir soporte a la empresa que lo provee ¿no crees que eso es lo correcto?

Comment: 1. No son problemas de configuración de cuentas, sino pasos a seguir. 2. Hay muchas empresas que tienen su soporte en SO ([con sus límites](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/83)). 3. Si todo aquello que pagamos quedara fuera de SO, poca cosa preguntaríamos aquí... ¿O acaso no son pertinentes las preguntas de Intellij IDEA, Lotus, o vete a saber cuántas tecnologías o herramientas de pago?

Comment: @fedorqui como te das cuenta siempre hay huecos, y ese es el objetivo de mi pregunta, ojala alla alguna otra respuesta que contradiga mis afirmaciones y señale como distinguir entre casos válidos e inválidos.

Comment: ¡Claro! Y es bueno debatirlo aquí para tener algo tangible con lo que ir al sitio principal a preguntar :) Yo me guié por [so], donde vi bastantes preguntas al respecto ([ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37094820/1983854) o [también este](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40955368/1983854)). Allí en SO suelen ser más estrictos porque además tienen un amalgama de sitios donde migrar, pero quise saber antes cómo se veía aquí en SOes.

Comment: @fedorqui claro, esas preguntas son válidas en SO ya que no son de soporte, sino preguntas que surgen al momento de implementar un software, si te das cuenta no pregunta como hacer algo sino que han avanzado y tuvieron un problema.

Comment: (por cierto, el voto negativo no es mío :P sé que no hace falta decirlo, pero lo creo relevante)

Comment: En realidad no me interesan los votos a per se, ese voto solo me indica que un miembro de la comunidad no esta de acuerdo con mi posición y lo cual es natural ya que probablemente para él ese tipo de preguntas deberias ser válidas aqui ya que como no esta delimitado claramente que es válido o no aquí. Lo mismo me sucedio en otras preguntas/respuestas :-). Pero seria genial que otros usuarios respondan.