# Nueva etiqueta RestSharp, Solicitar un link a SO esp

Tags: discusión, temática

Con Lois6b estábamos tratando de ayudar a un nuevo usuario con la pregunta:

[Checkout personalizado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/checkout-personalizado)

Mas allá de la etiqueta [mercadopago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago), OP usa una librería llamada RestSharp para las consultas REST desde .net

Investigando un poco, la etiqueta no existía en SOesp, asi que la cree ([restsharp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restsharp)) y llene toda la información, copiando la información que existe en SO.

Esto me surgió, porque al entrar en la pagina del [proyecto](http://restsharp.org/), descubro que aparte de ser un proyecto libre, incitan a los usuarios a poner sus consultas en SO eng.

Haciendo un poco de investigación, en So eng hay 1295 preguntas taggeadas con RestSharp, y buscando un poco, en Portugues y Ruso la etiqueta no existe, pero hay 21 y 19 preguntas respectivamente que hacen referencia a esa librería.

En nuestro sitio, hice una búsqueda, y había por lo menos 2 preguntas mas que merecían esa etiqueta, a las cuales ya se las agregue.

Ahora, y miro a JuanM, no estaría bueno conectarse con la gente que maneja el proyecto RestSharp, y preguntarles si no quieren aprovechar y ya que linkean a SO eng, también aclaren que si las preguntas son en español podrían preguntar aquí?

Comment: ¿En tu investigación observaste si el proyecto en cuestión maneja documentación en español?

Comment: no lo maneja. tambien por ahi es una buena forma de unir hispano parlantes al proyecto?. @Rubén

Comment: Creo que la idea de conectar con los dirigen proyectos de código abierto es genial, pero más que pasar la responsabilidad a Juan me parece que alguno de los asiduos interesado en proyectos de este tipo deberían asumir la labor de "embajadores". ¿Cómo vez? ¿te apuntas?

Comment: venga vamos! Utilizo RestSharp y es la voz para hacer RESTful services. Sencillo y bien powerful!

Comment: ahi @fredyfx se apunto.. jajajaja...

Comment: Únanse y empiezen los pasos para contactar a los que deben enterarse de esto. Si me necesitan para algo oficial, aquí estoy. 

Comment: al brother de RestSharp le envié unos tweets y mientras que no hay respuesta. Acabo de hacer un pull request: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/1008 :D

Comment: el tweeter ese no parece vivo :p

Comment: lamento informarles hermanos que el autor desistió de aceptar la iniciativa https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/1008

Comment: ok.. Una pena.. el se lo pierde :p.. Algun mod que cierre esto con estado-rechazado???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece una buena idea hablar con esta gente. Sin embargo, creo que sería tan simple como hacer un *pull request* para modificar la página del proyecto en la que explican cómo colaborar:

Lo siguiente ya no existe, es del año 2015:

- [index.html - RestSharp - commit hecho el 12 de octubre del 2015 - línea 37)](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/ea9ee18813ae5d6759baccfed6e4e38a908f89d2/index.html#L37)

Al siguiente commit, hecho en enero del año 2020, lo quitaron:

- [index.html - RestSharp - commit hecho el 6 de enero del 2010](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/ebbf1760892e5b81e3a7df2bc72d46c87cd512e4#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3bL37)

Este cambio se puede ver en el siguiente enlace:

- [Historia del archivo index.html - RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commits/gh-pages/index.html)

Código:

```html
<p><strong>Post your question on <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restsharp">StackOverflow</a></strong>. If you think you've found a bug, create an issue on GitHub.</p>
```

Resultado:

> **Post your question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restsharp)**. If you think you've found a bug, create an issue on GitHub.

Falta mencionar SOpt, SOru y SOes.

---

A pesar de esto, se puede ver algo similar en el siguiente enlace, donde `restsharp` conduce a su etiqueta en Stack Overflow:

- [RestSharp/docs/get-help/README.md # Questions](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blame/48312d1e7f1e082345e147fa53b516937e179d35/docs/get-help/README.md#L4-L12)

Resultado:

> ### Questions
>
> The most effective way to resolve questions about using RestSharp is StackOverflow.
>
> RestSharp has a large user base. Tens of thousands of projects and hundreds of thousands of developers use RestSharp on a daily basis. So, asking questions on StackOverflow with [restsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restsharp) tag would most definitely lead you to a solution.

---

Creo que apelamos demasiado a la jerarquía organizativa de Stack Exchange y esperamos que las cosas, se gestionen "desde arriba". Sin embargo, también observo que nunca se hizo nada con Mercadopago.

Discusiones:

1. [¿Como actuar frente a empresas, externos que redirigen sus foros acá?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1674)
2. [Foro de Mercado Pago](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2380)
3. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2682 (eliminada)

Los [textos sin traducir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40) se acumulan, lo mismo pasa con las [malas traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83), los [bugs](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20%5Bbug%5D%20-%5Bestado-*%5D) y tantas otras cosas. Por tanto, seguramente es bueno que nos acostumbremos a solucionar las cosas que estén en nuestra mano, y esta es una de ellas.

Comment: adhiero,... estaria bien.,. pero que los rusos y portugueses se las arreglen solitos ;)