# ¿Por qué se deniega soporte a Woocommerce?

Tags: soporte, motivos-de-cierre, temática, pregunta-específica

Esta mañana me encontré con un tema donde se le decía al OP que no recibiría soporte y probablemente su consulta fuera cerrada por que era de Woocommerce, y que debería ir a su soporte. Aquí os dejo el hilo:

[cómo transferir variables de un sitio wordpress a un sitio php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121216/c%C3%B3mo-transferir-variables-de-un-sitio-wordpress-a-un-sitio-php)

¿No es un poco relativo el decir que no se da soporte por que pertenece a Woocommerce?, entonces ¿por qué sí damos soporte cuando se trata de un wordpress, prestashop o cualquier otro cms?, o cuando se trata de un problema con jQuery... también son empresas las que están por detrás de todo esto ¿mandamos al foro de jQuery a todas las personas que tengan problemas con ello?.

Entiendo que la línea de a qué dar soporte pueda llegar a ser muy fina, entiendo que a servicios de pago los responsables del soporte, puedan llegar a ser dichas empresas (por estar cobrando ese servicio).

Leí la ayuda sobre esto, pero sigue sen quedarme totalmente claro dónde está esa línea que separa lo que podemos o no podemos responder.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que en un muy alto porcentaje de los casos de preguntas con el tag Woocomerce o MercadoPago entran en la categoría de soporte, ya que son problemas que probablemente solo pueden resolver los responsables de dichas plataformas.Este alto porcentaje hace que la tendencia sea a cerrar casi todas las preguntas de esos tags, y sea posible que en alguna ocasión se pueda tomar como pregunta no adecuada alguna que realmente si tiene sentido en el sitio. De todas maneras, no recuerdo prácticamente ninguna pregunta de esos tags que haya recibido una sola respuesta.

Comment: Relacionado: [Foro de Mercado Pago](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2380) y [¿Como actuar frente a empresas, externos que redirigen sus foros acá?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1674) y [¿Por qué no somos soporte al cliente de tu compañía favorita?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525)

Comment: Pero la pregunta en concreto, trata sobre la API de WP y Woocommerce... no relacionada con la pasarela si no con los datos de usuario (wp-users)...

Comment: Como te digo en mi comentario, es posible que en alguna ocasión, por las razones que te he explicado, se nos "cuele" alguna pregunta que si entra dentro de la temática del sitio. En ese caso, como tu has hecho, lo mejor es traer el caso aqui y si es asi probablemente se proceda a su  reapertura.

Comment: @Pikoh su reapertura, pero es importante sea re formulada de acuerdo a lo definido en el [help], para que no sea cerrada nuevamente.

Comment: Esta pregunta es un ejemplo de porqué muchas preguntas de woocomerce y mercadopago son cerradas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/122619/15301

Answer (score 4):

> [...] que no recibiría soporte y probablemente su consulta fuera cerrada por que era de Woocommerce

No veo que se le haya dicho eso.

> ¿No es un poco relativo el decir que no se da soporte por que pertenece a Woocommerce?

No sería *relativo*, estaría mal. Pero definitivamente no se le dijo eso.

---

**¿Qué se le dijo?**

Cuando se menciona al "*soporte de Woocommerce*", se está haciendo referencia a que es un problema a consultar con el **departamento de Soporte** (o la ayuda online) de esa empresa. Esto es muy diferente a decir que no se le da soporte a preguntas de WooCommerce.

El tema central acá es que no hay un problema de código... O, si lo hubiera, no está especificado en la pregunta.

Esta pregunta se cerró, de la misma forma que se hubiese cerrado una pregunta consultando por qué API de Google usar para `[seleccione un problema]`.

**Puede malinterpretarse**

Es cierto que los comentarios y el cierre pueden malinterpretarse como tal. Creo que es un buen punto el que estás trayendo. Me parece que podríamos intentar ser más claros en que ese **tipo** de preguntas no son aceptadas, pero que cualquier otra pregunta de esa empresa que trate sobre código sí.

---

> también son empresas las que están por detrás de todo esto

Cualquier producto/api/ws/servicio/etc. de cualquier empresa es bienvenido, e incluso se alienta a que haya una buena interacción con los desarrolladores de esa empresa, participando activamente en el sitio.

El hecho de que actualmente haya [68 preguntas abiertas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D%20closed%3Ano) etiquetadas como WooCommerce en el sitio da cuenta de esto.

> Entiendo que la línea de a qué dar soporte pueda llegar a ser muy fina, entiendo que a servicios de pago los responsables del soporte, puedan llegar a ser dichas empresas (por estar cobrando ese servicio).
>
> [...] sigue sen quedarme totalmente claro donde está esa línea que separa lo que podemos o no podemos responder

No creo que sea una línea de división fina. Incluso un servicio/producto/etc. pago también es bien recibido. La línea divisoria es muy sencilla: **¿se trata de un problema de programación?**.

---

**Cuál es la postura de SOes frente a preguntas de productos de otras empresas**

Está perfectamente descripto en [¿Por qué no somos soporte al cliente de [tu compañía favorita]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/127)

Este fue el enlace que se le dio en el primer comentario.

Comment: "Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque pertenece al soporte de Woocommerce".

Comment: @jonilgz entiendo que el "soporte de Woocommerce" hace referencia al "departamento de Soporte", como puse en mi respuesta... Así como me parece un buen punto el que marcaste, a mejorar, que la descripción en el cierre debería ser más atinada.

Comment: @jonilgz Ese comentario fue mio y no es muy afortunado. Evidentemente, me refería a que correspondía al departamento de soporte de Woocomerce mas que a SOes.

Comment: Entiendo los puntos expuestos, pero sigo pensando que si el usuario tal como dice Pablo Lozano, hubiese puesto el código que le está dando problemas, ¿la pregunta ya correspondería a SOes? Osea, esta persona tiene dudas de como obtener datos de la DB de WP. Esto puede realizarse mediante la API de WP, la API DE WC o incluso con PHP nativo realizando tu propia conexión a la DB, por lo que entiendo es una pregunta de programación, de ahí mi inquietud en el tema. Cierto es, que no cumple todos los requisitos de la pregunta, pues no proporciona su intento de realización ni aporta código alguno.

Comment: @jonilgz Realmente no estoy tan convencido de que el problema sea cómo obtener los datos, pero prefiero no intentar adivinar qué es lo que intentó preguntar... Sin duda, si el autor de la pregunta la modificara para mostrar un problema específico de código, se reabriría.

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinión debería estar cerrada pero por otro motivo: La pregunta es muy amplia y no se ha añadido código o algo que ayude a entender exactamente qué se quiere hacer y por qué no se ha podido resolver hasta ahora.

En otras palabras: La pregunta está dentro de la temática de StackOverflow en español, pero no es una buena pregunta. Pienso que se debería reabrir y, si no mejora, cerrar por el motivo correcto.

Comment: Efectivamente, ese debería ser el procedimiento.

Comment: El propósito de un cierre es para que se mejore la pregunta. El motivo del cierre fue como no relacionado porque *no parece ser sobre programación*, lo cual es correcto. No se reabren preguntas para ver si se mejoran. Es al revés, si se mejoran pueden reabrirse.

Comment: Yo creo que sí versa sobre programación pero no ha puesto el código. Tienes razón en los pasos que se tienen que dar, se abriría si mejora.

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente todas las preguntas que tengan que ver con programación son bienvenidas en el sitio. **No se niega el "soporte" o ayuda a nadie, el requisito importante es que la pregunta debe cumplir con las reglas del [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)**, esto para evitar sea ["cerrada" o puesta en "espera"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Incluso como comentan puede ser reabierta si es reformulada correctamente.

La pregunta sin duda debe ser cerrada puesto que es "demasiado amplia", lo cual desgraciadamente es muy común en las preguntas de esta etiqueta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce

es importante el mensaje que agrega Mariano, con lo cual se puede responder a la pregunta:

> Entiéndase que el cierre de esta pregunta fue por no tratar sobre
>   programación (o no tener la descripción que haga referencia y el
>   código con el problema), sino más bien algo a preguntar en el
>   departamento de Soporte de WooCommerce. **Todas las preguntas de
>   WooCommerce son bienvenidas, siempre que traten de un problema
>   específico de código**... Si crees que podés orientar tu pregunta a un
>   problema de código, por favor intenta editar la pregunta mostrando tu
>   código y en qué parte estás teniendo el problema y seguramente se
>   reabra.

**La pregunta puede ser reabierta pero teniendo el formato actual si no es re formulada, seguramente tendrá el mismo destino.**

Si en tu opinión consideras que la pregunta a la que se hace referencia es  válida", para que no existan mal entendidos te sugiero revisar [Centro de Ayuda > Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).