# ¿Se debería hacer algo en particular con el caso de MercadoPago?

Tags: discusión

He leído en Meta alguna pregunta sobre el tema de MercadoPago. Por ejemplo:

- [Foro de Mercado Pago](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2380/29967)
- [¿Como actuar frente a empresas, externos que redirigen sus foros acá?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1674/29967)
- [¿Por qué no somos soporte al cliente de [tu compañía favorita]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/29967)

Estoy acostumbrado a ver muchas preguntas sobre esta plataforma de muy mala calidad.

Hoy mismo por ejemplo, con pocos horas de diferencia:

> ## Transaccion en curso MercadoPago modulo Prestashop
>
> recibi una compra y la transaccion figura en curso desde hace unos
> dias. No entiendo si se realizo o no. Como deberi seguir?

Y también esta otra:

> ## Error SDK Mercado Pago Android
>
> Tengo un error al iniciar un Checkout de MercadoPago con el SDK de
> Android en mi app, cuando lo integré, se desplegaba la vista, días
> después dejó de funcionar con un mensaje de "Uy! Ha ocurrido un error.
> Intente más tarde" y nunca funcionaba.
>
> Copiando y pegando el mismo código en una nueva app diferente, si
> funciona.
>
> ¿Cuál es el problema?

Ambos OPs tienen un punto de reputación.

Cuando uno ve eso, da la impresión de que MercadoPago *parasita* de alguna manera Stackoverflow.

Aún en el caso de que la plataforma tuviese expertos dedicados a responder este tipo de dudas/problemas aquí, sigo pensando que este tipo de preguntas parasitan a Stackoverflow y que además la mayoría de quienes plantean preguntas de este tipo no se quedan luego en la red (sería interesante evaluar ese dato a través de Data StackExcange)...

Entonces, mi pregunta es si no se podría/debería emprender alguna acción, sea de parte de Stackoverflow, sea de parte de nosotros, para evitar que este tipo de preguntas se multipliquen en este sitio.

Yo no me refiero a emprender acciones sobre la etiqueta en sí, sino acciones reales. Alguna iniciativa de nuestra parte, y/o de parte de algún empleado de Stackoverflow.

La situación de `mercadopago` aquí me parece una situación extrema, en el sentido de que no sólo mandan las preguntas aquí, si no que además, la experiencia demuestra que aquí no hay nadie o casi nadie, ningún empleado o especialista de ellos dedicado a resolver al menos una o dos preguntas de estas todos los días.

Quizá una acción eficaz podría pasar incluso por hacer ver a los responsables de Mercadopago una situación que debería ser motivo de vergüenza para ellos, si se consideran una empresa seria que debería tener como una de sus prioridades el soporte a los usuarios.

**P.D.** Estuve leyendo algunas de las preguntas planteadas sobre esto. En alguna de ellas se llegó a una discusión amplia sobre el tema y está llena de respuestas, pero de aquello es difícil sacar algo en limpio. Por eso estoy planteando esta pregunta y porque creo que a MercadoPago hay que echarle de comer aparte, ya que a veces aparecen preguntas en una cantidad exagerada aquí.

Comment: @Mariano no se encontro pagina o.O

Comment: ah ok @Mariano, por cierto un gusto saludarte

Answer (score 4):

[Votemos por el contenido y no por la persona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1935/votemos-por-contenido-no-por-personas?s=1%7C34.2536)

Y en la misma línea diré : Votemos y actuemos respecto al contenido y no respecto a la temática de la pregunta. Siendo que la temática en este caso está dentro de lo que se puede preguntar en el sitio.

Las medídas generales respecto a un framework, plataforma, lenguaje, etc son una señal de mala moderación. Incluso si para un framework el 90% de las preguntas fuesen basura eso no justifica cargarse de un plumazo o tomar otras medidas perjudiciales para el 10% de gemas mezcladas con la basura. **Una buena moderación evalua cada pregunta en si misma.**

¿Somos moderadores de brocha gorda o de pincel fino?

Comment: Me encantó como lo planteaste. Excelentes todos los puntos que mencionaste. Sólo quería comentar que estoy de totalmente de acuerdo, pero que también creo que *podrían* haber acciones para mejorar ese 90% (en particular, que SOes no aparezca simplemente como "*Foro de desarrolladores*", o que se genere una especie de *recorrido* a quien llega por ese link, o alguna acción similar).

Answer (score 3):

Lo que es evidente es que las preguntas de [mercadopago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago) rara vez obtienen respuesta. Actualmente existen 151 preguntas con el tag [mercadopago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago), de las cuales solo 67 han obtenido al menos una respuesta,y solo 15 de estas han sido aceptadas.

La cuestión es que no podemos evitar que se utilice ya que al fin y al cabo, aquellas que no se refieren a Soporte del propio MercadoPago, si entran dentro de la temática del sitio. En mi caso el problema es que se me hace difícil distinguir si son preguntas de soporte o de programación.

Yo creo que mas que hacer algo directamente contra el tag por si mismo, lo que deberíamos hacer es cerrar las preguntas que tengan una falta de calidad clara, lo cual suelen ser la mayoría. Si las analizamos, la mayoría de ellas entran en categorías como *Demasiado amplia*, *No está claro lo que se pregunta*, o al menos en *No relacionado, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado...*

**Edit:**

Como bien dice @Mariano, a los datos que he dado sobre la etiqueta hay que añadir las preguntas que fueron eliminadas. Gracias a el, podéis consultarlas aquí: Son 238 preguntas eliminadas para sumar a tus estadísticas --> data.stackexchange . Son 238 mas.

Comment: Además, los números los estás sacando de las preguntas actuales, pero pensá en todas las que se eliminaron por estar cerradas por ROOMBA!!! Estoy de acuerdo con el resto, aunque creo que la acción correctiva la debería hacer JuanM u otro empleado de SO

Comment: @mariano efectivamente,los datos son de las preguntas activas. Si sumamos las eliminadas todavía es mas evidente que esa etiqueta tiene un porcentaje extremadamente alto de preguntas de baja calidad o directamente fuera de tema

Comment: Son 238 preguntas eliminadas para sumar a tus estadísticas --> http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/790269/mp-lpqtp

Comment: Tu respuesta parece demasiado centrada al tag `Mercadopago`, yo no estoy preguntando sobre el tag, sobre si debemos actuar sobre él, sobre si debemos eliminarlo. Como dijo @Mariano acertadamente, eliminar el tag crearía una situación peor ya que sería difícil encontrar esas preguntas locas pululando por la red. Mi pregunta busca una respuesta sobre qué actitudes se pueden emprender de manera concreta, por nosotros y quizá también por algún empleado de SO, para evitar que `Mercadopago` parasite esta red. Me parece una situación extrema, en el sentido de que no sólo mandan las preguntas aquí...

Comment: ... si no que además, la experiencia demuestra que aquí no hay nadie o casi nadie, ningún empleado o especialista de ellos dedicado a resolver al menos una o dos preguntas de estas todos los días. Yo me pregunto cómo la gente puede usa una plataforma que observa un comportamiento tan mediocre en algo tan importante como es el soporte. Una acción eficaz podría pasar incluso por hacer ver a los responsables de `Mercadopago` una situación que debería ser motivo de vergüenza para ellos, si se consideran una empresa seria.

Answer (score -2):

Habría que verificar las preguntas en sí, si son problemas para soporte o problemas de programación.

Aunque la etiqueta `mercadopago`incluye todo lo relacionado a él.

> Cuando uno ve eso, da la impresión de que MercadoPago parasita de alguna manera Stackoverflow.

He pensado en que quizas se deberia de abrir una comunidad aparte ej:
`mercadopago.stackoverflow.com`

Creo que si se plantease la propuesta de una *comunidad* especialmente para problemas con *mercadopago* se limpiaria un poco lo que es *en general* el listado de preguntas etc.

Con respecto a las *preguntas de mala calidad* se deberian de "cerrar" o "poner en espera" de acuerdo con [*¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Si estás un rato leyendo las preguntas que aparecen en el sitio, vas a ver varias de MP que no son de programación. Y si pasás por las colas de revisión, aún más... Pero nadie habló de "quitar la etiqueta", eso sería más problemático aún (preguntas malas y mal etiquetadas!)

Comment: @Mariano estoy a 5 minutos de escribir un Te he votado negativamente porque MP te mando aca.. :p.. pero a segundos eh... aunque no te guste :p

Comment: Mil disculpas, interprete mal la pregunta. Ya edite mi respuesta. :)

Comment: Se puede proponer un nuevo sitio en [a51], cualquiera puede hacerlo, aunque dudo que progrese... Ya de por sí el soporte es pésimo, la respuesta en este sitio es mala, la participación de empleados de MP es nula, o incluso resta más de lo que aporta... En definitiva, son un desastre, por lo que proponer un sitio aparte me suena a una mala idea.

Comment: Entonces veo nula o dificil la solución a esta pregunta. En mi caso.