# ¿Revisión antes de publicar?

Tags: discusión

Como sabréis  [wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) es uno de los `CMS`más utilizado actualmente y que no requiere escribir ni unas sola línea de código para montar una web. Junto con el plugin [woocommerce](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) ofrece la oportunidad de crear una tienda online completamente funcional, si a la ecuación le añadimos el 'método de pago X',   acabamos de crear una 'bomba de relojería'.

Con lo de bomba de relojería me refiero a que los problemas derivados por el uso de este `CMS`pueden ser de programación, puesto que se pueden desarrollar [wordpress-theme](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-theme) y también [wordpress-plugin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin), o pueden ser problemas de simple 'montaje' incluso de soporte técnico de plugins desarrollado por terceros.

Esto da lugar a tener un cúmulo de preguntas no relacionadas con votos negativos, que nadie responde, con comentarios de bienvenida y recomendación de reformular la pregunta pero poco más. Entiendo que se van moderando, pero la posibilidad de reformular algunas preguntas para que se adapten a los requerimientos del sitio son casi nulas.

La pregunta es:

**¿Existe la posibilidad de revisar estas preguntas antes de publicarlas?**

**¿Estaría este procedimiento en contra de la filosofía o las reglas de Stackoverflow en español?**

**EDITO:**
Elimino la etiqueta [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva) puesto que no pretendía que se agregara esto como funcionalidad, solo me interesaba saber si existía algún método para evitarlo o si estaría en contra de la filosofía del sitio.

Comment: Entiendo que pides una cola de revision y las aceptadas sean publicadas. Pero eso tambien se podria aplicar a cualquier otro cierre, como preguntas en inglés. Hay colas que ya mismo están saturadas y que tardan en limpiarse. No creo que los usuarios que publiquen preguntas buenas quieran esperar 1-2 dias a que su pregunta esté publicada en el siito. Un saludo

Comment: Hola @lois6b, entiendo los inconvenientes de alquien que publica una pregunta válida y tiene que esperar un tiempo para verla. Veo un pequeño matiz entre las preguntas en inglés y estas que comento, las preguntas en inglés pueden adaptarse a las normas modificándolas, estas en particular nunca se adaptarán a las normas y entiendo que es algo que puede pasar en todo el sitio en general, pero como usuario frecuente de estas etiquetas veo esta pequeña particularidad. Me interesa saber la opinión que tenéis y si esta medida se adaptaría a las normas del sitio. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Yo no apoyaria una iniciativa asi. El sistema que seguimos no está solo establecido aqui si no en todos los sitios de la Red StackExchange (que yo sepa) e implementarlo lo considero un tanto redundante. El problema de estas preguntas que mencionas es visto en cualquier otra etiqueta cuando un usuario no lee bien las normas de calidad y si bien en estas etiquetas que mencionas se puede dar más, solo queda esperar a que haya más expertos de estas tecnologias que puedan mejorar si cabe las pregunta y si no, cerradas por el motivo que aplique.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Se debería hacer algo en particular con el caso de MercadoPago?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3073/15301)

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, es cierto que puede estar relacionado, pero pretendía hacer visible la dualidad que existe en wordpress en general por la dualidad que tiene como gestor de contenidos y marco de desarrollo y las confusiones que eso provoca en los usuarios de este sitio.

Comment: Bueno Ernesto, todo software tiene sus particularidades. Pero el caso que nos ocupa, no es un problema de Wordpress, sino de que MercadoPago enlaza a este sitio como si fuera su soporte personal. De ahi vienen todas esas preguntas que resultan ser insalvables. De todas maneras, la única solución que yo veo con las herramientas disponibles, es activar la cola de _triage_, que tal vez aceleraría el proceso de cierre de esas preguntas de baja calidad.

Comment: Ya, entiendo, gracias a todos por comentar, tenía esta duda y ya me queda resuelta. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Resumen

Me parece exagerado llamarle "una bomba de relojería" ya que la etiqueta [wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tienes menos de mil preguntas siendo que en el sitio en inglés tiene más de cien mil y las otras etiquetas cada una tiene menos de cien. En cualquier caso no está de más estar atentos a los índices de preguntas respondidas y de seguir las recomendaciones de [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65).

## Extenso

> ¿Existe la posibilidad de revisar estas preguntas antes de publicarlas?

Por un revisor, actualmente no es posible.

Cabe destacar que las primeras publicaciones de todos los usuarios pasan en automático a una cola de revisión específica, la cola de primeras publicaciones. Por otro lado, se puede realizar y discutir propuestas al respecto, pero hay que tener en cuenta que lo que implique modificar el software, seguramente deberá ser escalado a Meta SE pues podría afectar a otros sitios de la red.

> ¿Estaría este procedimiento en contra de la filosofía o las reglas de Stackoverflow en español?

Con respecto al modelo actual, sí, estaría en contra.

Una de las "reglas" del modelo de Stack Exchange es que cualquiera puede publicar, de hecho no es necesario registrarse para hacerlo. Existen algunas limitaciones, por ejemplo, el número de publicaciones que pueden hacerse en un lapso de tiempo determinado. Estas limitaciones se modifican de forma automática conforme el uso que se haga del sitio, si se usa bien, se amplían los límites, si se usa mal, se reducen o incluso se puede llegar a bloquear al usuario.

Cabe mencionar que el sitio cuenta con varios "mecanismos" de depuración automática de "malas" publicaciones los cuales se describen en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/65) así que no te preocupes en que el sitio "se llene de basura".

Por otro lado hace falta que como comunidad participemos más, en particular que sean más los usuarios que lo hacen, votando y revisando al tiempo que somos amables tanto con los que conocen el modelo como con los que no.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, quizás sí ha sido un poco exagerado llamarlo bomba de relojería. Ahora ya lo tengo 100% claro. Un saludo!